# Running same script in all nodes in a Hub using Robot Framework

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium-grid

I'm working on a load test for an web platform at the moment and I need a way to execute the same test script in all nodes in a Selenium Hub in Docker containers. We use the Robot Framework for our test scripts and so far I've been able to run test in suites in parallel using all the nodes with Pabot, but that's not exactly the goal. I need a way to run the exact same test script and also target a specific node in the hub to be used, but I couldn't find the information on how to do it anywhere.

So in summary, we are using Robot Framework to run tests on a website. I need a way to run a load test that executes the same script in dozens of containers and indicate which node I want to use for a given test.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.